# Where does chocolatey install sysinternals?

Tags: process-explorer, chocolatey, sysinternals

Chocolatey has a nice sysinternals package, but where does it install to?  (by default)

https://chocolatey.org/packages/sysinternals

Comment: Universal way: `echo %ChocolateyInstall%\lib\sysinternals\tools`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The install location is here:

C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sysinternals\tools

On Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10.

Or as Alex above suggested `the universal way` with environment variables:

```
echo %ChocolateyInstall%\lib\sysinternals\tools
```